# DropDownListFor not appearing in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

This is a part of my controller:

```
    // GET
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var query = from f in db.Stages
                    select f;
        var sItems = new SelectList(query, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.StagesList = sItems;
        return View();
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, ViewBag.StagesList as SelectList)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
    </div>
```

But dropdownlist not appearing in view.Why? What is the problem?

Comment: Is the dropdown present in the generated HTML when you view the source in your browser? Also could there be some javascript or CSS on your page which might be hiding it?

Comment: Yes, dropdown presents in the generated HTML. No there is no javascript code or CSS to hide that

Comment: Then you should be able to see it :-) Could you post the exact HTML rendered in your browser?

Comment: I changed the selectlist to selectlistitem and the problem solved. I don't know the difference between them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be in the view but suffering from a logic flaw or there is a missing end-tag somewhere.  Use the view source option of the browser to try to find the element to see if it's rendering.  I'm guessing that it is, but is rendering no items and not showing anything, or there is a syntax error somewhere (though that usually doesn't hide it).